# Merge dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I'm trying to merge this two dataframes:

```
df1=  
     pais   ano  cantidad
 0  Chile  2000        10
 1  Chile  2001        11
 2  Chile  2002        12

df2=
     pais   ano  cantidad
 0  Chile  1999         0
 1  Chile  2000         0
 2  Chile  2001         0
 3  Chile  2002         0
 4  Chile  2003         0
```

I'm trying to merge df1 into df2 and replace the existing año rows with those from df1. This is the code that I'm trying right now and what I'm getting:

```
df=df1.combine_first(df2)

df=
    pais    ano     cantidad
0   Chile   2000.0  10.0
1   Chile   2001.0  11.0
2   Chile   2002.0  12.0
3   Chile   2002.0  0.0
4   Chile   2003.0  0.0
```

As you can see, row corresponding to 1999 is missing and the one for 2002 with 'cantidad'= 0 shoudn't be there. My desired output is this:

```
df=
    pais    ano     cantidad
0   Chile   1999    0
1   Chile   2000    10
2   Chile   2001    11
3   Chile   2002    12
4   Chile   2003    0
```

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Why do you have 2 rows with `2002` but just one row with `2000`?

Comment: @QuangHoang my mistake, it should be one 2002 (the one with cantidad 12).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform a [`left join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) on `df2` and [`fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) missing values from `df2.cantidad`. I'm joining on `pais` and `ano` because I assume in your real dataframe are more countries than 'chile'.

```
df = df2[['pais','ano']].merge(df1, on=['pais','ano'], how='left').fillna({'cantidad': df2.cantidad})
df.cantidad = df.cantidad.astype('int')
df
```

Out:

```
    pais   ano  cantidad
0  Chile  1999         0
1  Chile  2000        10
2  Chile  2001        11
3  Chile  2002        12
4  Chile  2003         0
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly was I was looking for. And yes, there are more countries, so thanks for be thoughtful about that too!

Answer (score 1):

Add `how='outer` param to the merge.

By default, `merge` works with "inner", which means it takes only values which are in both dataframe (intersection) while you want union of those sections.

Also, you may want to add `on="ano"` to declare on which column you want to merge. It may not be needed on your case, but it's worth to check it out.

Please check [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101) for more details

Comment: Thanks! I'll check that info.